# URLs and navigation in custom themes

Tags: customization, url-rewriting, navigation

I have created a custom theme for my site, using stand-alone PHP files (PHP files that are not associated with core, plugins or WordPress themes, eg index.php, header.php ...).

In case anyone is interested, this page explains very well how to do it: https://zeropointdevelopment.com/how-to-use-wordpress-functions-in-a-non-wordpress-custom-php-file-wpquickies/

The question is the following: in my local environment the URL of my site is: http: // localhost / xxx / which shows the index.php (so far everything normal). On this page I have a link to one of these stand-alone PHP files, for example to example.php. When navigating to this file the URL is the following:
http: // localhost / xxx / wp-content / themes / xxx-theme / example.php

I have created the link like this:

`<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?> \ example.php "> Example </a>`

example.php is in the same directory as index.php, but if I create the link as shown below it doesn't work, WordPress can't find the file.

`<a href="example.php"> Example </a>`

I think it would be more correct if the URLs to the stand-alone PHP files were more friendly, for example: http: // localhost / xxx / example.php (when I access my site I don't go to the URL http:
//  localhost / xxx / wp-content / themes / xxx-theme / index.php).

Is there a way to handle URLs in WordPress? Is there a better approach to this that I expose?

Thanks in advance and greetings!!

Comment: Why did you do it this way? If you're linking these files directly then why would they be in the theme directory if they're not theme templates? Just move the files to the root directory, then you can link to them at the paths you want. Otherwise you should start over and develop the theme the proper way and make templates that can be assigned to WordPress Pages.

Comment: Thank you so much Jacob Peattie! I have put an example file in the root and everything seems to work perfectly. In the theme files I point to the files that are in the root like this: `<a href="<?php echo get_site_url() . "/example.php"; ?>">X</a>`. I don't know if this is the best way. Better a link relative to my site?. In the example file in the root I make a require_once of the wp-load.php file to be able to use the WordPress API:`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/xxx'.'/wp-load.php')`

Comment: This is absolutely not the best way. The best way is to develop a theme properly and add content through WordPress. What WordPress functions do you even need to use if you’re not developing a theme?

Comment: I am using WordPress as a kind of "framework".  In the index of the web a presentation of the theme of the site is made and allows you to log in or register.  To separate functionalities, I had thought of creating, for example, a php file for the user registry, another for a list with a search by filters... each functionality of the web in its corresponding file/s.  I come from the development in Java and its different frameworks, it is possible that I am trying to bring this philosophy to WordPress and this is not the way.

Comment: You defiantly don't need to do it this way.  What you should be doing is building those custom functionalities as plugins within minimal styling and keep them separate from the theme, that way, if in a few years time you want to change the theme, you can just focus on that and not worry about transferring all the custom functionality across.

Comment: Hi, Tony!  I have visited your profile and I agree to use WP as a framework, I am on the way to learn this.  If I implement these functionalities in components, wouldn't this make Index.php very complex?  Using parameters, should I call some components or others?  My doubts are still too general, do you know any manual to use WP as a framework for applications?  Orient you more to structuring a site instead of just CMS.